# PHP preg_match captures not working as expected

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

```
<?php
$html = <<<EOD
dsfgvsdfgv
sdfgv
sdfgv
<span id="userStatusText" class="text-overflow ng-binding userstatus-editable" title="_epic Can I have Coffee" ng-class="{'userstatus-editable':profileHeaderLayout.mayUpdateStatus}" ng-bind="profileHeaderLayout.statusText|statusfilter" ng-click="revealStatusForm()">"_epic Can I have Coffee"</span>
fdgvsdfgvsdfvg
var_dumpgv
dsfgv
EOD;

preg_match("!<span.+id=\"userStatusText\".+>(.*)<\/span>!", $html, $element);

if (!$element) {
  return;
}
echo $element[0];
```

I apologize for the atrocious variable, but I am trying to fetch `_epic Can I have Coffee` from the string.

I have been trying to fetch the string inside the parenthesis which were called captures on the PHP documentation.

I want to be able to capture the text inside (.*) which is not working.

When executing the preg_match, I would still get only the span element `<span ...>...</span>` (substitute ... for the content in the $html variable).

I have looked on several threads and documentation and couldn't find anything that would answer my issue.

Here is what it looks like when I execute it
[image]

I'm not trying to get the element but getting the text inside the  Right Here

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the Right here"? Do you wish to match text inside every spam tag, or just the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument) and [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) are the more appropriate way to parse HTML in PHP:

```
$html = <<<EOD
dsfgvsdfgv
sdfgv
sdfgv
<span id="userStatusText" class="text-overflow ng-binding userstatus-editable" title="_epic Can I have Coffee" ng-class="{'userstatus-editable':profileHeaderLayout.mayUpdateStatus}" ng-bind="profileHeaderLayout.statusText|statusfilter" ng-click="revealStatusForm()">"_epic Can I have Coffee"</span>
fdgvsdfgvsdfvg
var_dumpgv
dsfgv
EOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//span[@id="userStatusText"]') as $span) {
    echo $span->getAttribute('title');
}
```

Output:

```
_epic Can I have Coffee
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EdZCS)